# Changing Highcharts data series type dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have Highcharts with multiple series and 'select' for each series. My aim is to change series type via 'select'.

```
$('#ChType').change(function () {
    var series = chart.series[0]
    var newType = $('#ChType').val();
    changeType(series, newType);
})

$('#ChType2').change(function () {
    var series = chart.series[1]
    var newType = $('#ChType2').val();
    changeType(series, newType);
})

function changeType(series, newType) {
    var dataArray = [],
        points = series.data;
    series.chart.addSeries({
        type: newType,
        name: series.name,
        color: series.color,
        data: series.options.data
    }, false);
    alert(series.name);
    series.remove();
}
```

I understand that every time the type gets changed, series will get removed from it's current position in an array and added to the end. Currently I'm able to change only the series that is in the position series[0].

How can I change any other series and not just the series[0]?

I did see the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715733/fixing-discounting-a-data-series-when-changing-chart-type-in-highcharts) but couldn't quite get it to work.

My sample code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karin/waBck/3/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use v3.0 highcharts included series.update() method, which allows to change type of chart, dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Sg8K/1

```
chart.series[0].update({
                type: "column"
            });
```

Comment: It is added in head section, http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I've tested it in highcharts 3.0.0, here it is in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karin/GLdAY/), cleaner solution.

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul addSeries doesnt update serie, only add new, so how it is related with my answer?

Comment: yes you're right. I experiment a few try using update. AddSeries will definitely have to take down the selected series first

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you include the loop that you linked to in the similar question?

```
 $('#ChType').change(function(){
     var series;

     for ( i = 0 ; i < chart.series.length ; i++ ) {
            if ( chart.series[i].name == 'MyData1' ) {
                series = chart.series[i];

            }                
        } 
                 //var series = chart.series[0]
                 var newType = series.type == $('#ChType').val() ? $('#ChType').val()
```

Put that in place for each type - http://jsfiddle.net/waBck/5/