# Changing data series type dynamically with Highcharts-angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have an angular project with highcharts, using the official highcharts-angular wrapper. I want to display data either as bullet-chart or solid gauge. The user should be able to switch between the two. When I change the highcharts "options", I get

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at q.getExtremes (highcharts.src.js:30138)
    at q.getExtremes (bullet.src.js:279)
```

I also tried to use the Series.update method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15430520/11713600), but get the same error. You can reproduce it in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3x84z). The code basically does this:

```
    // initial options
    this.chartOptions =
    {
      series: [{
        "type": "solidgauge",
        "data": [{ "y": 380.2 }]
      }]
    };

    // after some delay, or when user clicks a button

    this.chartOptions =
    {
      series: [ {
        "type": "bullet",
        "data": [{ "y": 80.2 }]
      } ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Highcharts related to update `solidgauge` series type: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7746

As a workaround you can update `chart.type`:

```
setBullet() {
  const component = this;
  this.chartOptions =
    {
      chart: {
        type: 'bullet',
        ...
      },
      series: [...]
    };
}

setSolidGauge() {
  const component = this;
  this.chartOptions =
    {
      chart: {
        "type": "solidgauge",
        ...
      },
      series: [...]
    };
}
```

**Live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iktja5?file=src/app/chart.component.ts

Demo without Angular: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/30hn4ywb/